# Windows 10 removableStorage SQLite database

Tags: windows, sqlite, iot

I am trying to create an external sqlite database, I follow and tested text files in the removable storage and works. So then I try to create a database in the removable Storage:

```
public static async Task<String> CreateDatabase(string name)
    {
        var folder = await FindRemovableStorage();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            if(file!=null)
            {
                var ret = $"{folder.Name}{file.Name}";
                return ret;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

public async void ThirdCase()
    {
        var path =await DataLoggerService.CreateDatabase("db.dat");

        var connection = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path); //Cannot Open

    }
```

I am testing on the desktop, and returns CannotOpen. Does anyone has created a database out from the typical local folder?

More details of what I did here: [datalogger](http://expediteapps.com/blog/data-logger-with-windows-10-iot-in-progress/)

When I finish I want to implement in a Raspberry Pi, theorically is the same code for the Windows IoT or is there any change in the SQLitePlatformWinRT?

EDITION: More analisys:

I have tested a database with the typical, working like a charm:

```
Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.dat");
```

I wanted to create the database in an external storage, to do that I need to add the following steps:

1.- Add Capability to use removablestorage.
2.- Add file type association in order to have rights to manage that kind of files

(The details here: http://expediteapps.com/blog/data-logger-with-windows-10-iot-in-progress/)

So then I change the path to the removable storage path like “E:\db.dat” and it always tells CannotOpen.

The SQLite library PCL It arrives to here:

SQLiteApiWinRT.cs

```
public Result Open(byte[] filename, out IDbHandle db, int flags, IntPtr zvfs)
{
    Sqlite3DatabaseHandle internalDbHandle;
    var ret = (Result)SQLite3.Open(filename, out internalDbHandle, flags, zvfs);
    db = new DbHandle(internalDbHandle);
    return ret;
}
```

Where Open is

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open_v2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

public static extern Result Open(byte[] filename, out IntPtr db, int flags, IntPtr zvfs);

where I am using:

```
SQLite.UAP.2015, Version=3.8.10
```

MORE Aditions:

I have tested this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePortable/ and I finish in the same error, so it is internal.

And here is where the road ends, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for **RaspberryPi 3 Windows 10 IoT SQLite** implementation, here are the steps I followed to make it work: (Visual Studio 2015 Community)

1. Download: [.vsix package for Universal Windows Platform](http://sqlite.org/download.html) from the sqlite page
2. Install the package from the download folder
3. In Visual Studio go to Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager
   Console and type in: `Install-Package SQLite.Net-PCL`
4. Add required References (Right Mouse Button -> Add Reference ->
   Universal Windows -> Extensions)

Here I choose the following:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Universal
- SQLite for Universal Windows Platform
- Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps
- Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP (Since I am using RPi 3 with GPIO
  Pins)

Basically I followed [chrisbriggsy steps](http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Using-SQLITE-in-Windows-10-IoT-Core-Insider-Preview/) and had to add some more resources cause SQLite didn't work

Comment: 'Long time ago' I made this very complete article http://expediteapps.com/blog/storing-data-with-windows-10-iot/ I really dig into what it is possible and in case it has not changed, at this moment is not possible to use directly a database from an SDCard, that was my question here.

Comment: I really like your article - In case ANYBODY still struggles with creating it:
`path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);

conn.CreateTable<Message>();`